# Using Java 8, how do I read the contents of a file where I only attain what comes after the colon anywhere in the file?

Tags: java-8, io

My File below:

```
Start Simulator Configuration File
Version/Phase: 2.0
File Path: Test_2e.mdf
Projector cycle time {msec}: 25
Processor cycle time {msec}: 10
Keyboard cycle time {msec}: 50
Monitor display time {msec}: 20
Scanner cycle time {msec}: 10
Hard drive cycle time {msec}: 15
Log: Log to Both
Log File Path: logfile_1.lgf
End Simulator Configuration File
```

how do I read the file to where I only get what comes after the ": " 
There are ten items I need.

I managed to get this far:

```
public ConfigureClass(String fileName) throws IOException {


        BufferedReader inputStream = null; 

        try{

            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            String test; 
            int index = 0; 

            while((test = inputStream.readLine()) != null){

            arrOfStr[index++] = test.split(": ");


            }
            for(int i =0; i < index; i++){
                System.out.println(arrOfStr[i]);
            }

        } finally{
            if(inputStream != null){
                inputStream.close(); 
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

I split the file into lines. Every line is it's own string. I tried to split those strings by the colon to have two values, what is before then what is after. With the two values, I wanted to place them in the array. It would be nice to ignore the start simulator... and end simulator.. lines. I also must account for more cycle times to be in the file given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String[] arrOfStr;
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    arrOfStr = lines
            .skip(1).limit(10)
            .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf(": ")+2))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

This is only useful for the fixed structure shown in your sample file. Since you want to get an array, with a certain meaning for each index, it has to be that fixed.

Otherwise, consider using a `Map`:

```
Map<String,String> config;
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    config = lines
            .map(s -> s.split(": ", 2))
            .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
}
System.out.println("Log is "+config.getOrDefault("Log", "Undefined"));
System.out.println("All values:");
config.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("  "+key+" = "+value));
```

```
Log is Log to Both
All values:
  Processor cycle time {msec} = 10
  Keyboard cycle time {msec} = 50
  Projector cycle time {msec} = 25
  Hard drive cycle time {msec} = 15
  Log = Log to Both
  Scanner cycle time {msec} = 10
  Monitor display time {msec} = 20
  Version/Phase = 2.0
  File Path = Test_2e.mdf
  Log File Path = logfile_1.lgf
```

By the way, the next time you’re dealing with a `BufferedReader` (or any resource) manually, you should also use the [try-with-resource statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html), which handles closing automatically (and better than manual closing in a `finally` block):

```
String header;
Map<String,String> config;
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    header = br.readLine();
    config = br.lines()
      .map(s -> s.split(": ", 2))
      .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
}
System.out.println("Header is "+header);
System.out.println("Log is "+config.getOrDefault("Log", "Undefined"));
System.out.println("All values:");
config.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("  "+key+" = "+value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of doing it ....

- Use try with resources
- check if line contains `:` and split in 2 strings only and pick 2nd element
- removeIf line is empty or null

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(configureClass("c:/file.txt")));
    }

    public static String[] configureClass(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        // try with resources
        try (BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));) {
            String test;
            while ((test = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                // check if line contains ": "
                if (test.contains(": "))
                    // split into 2 strings and pick 2
                    lines.add(test.split(": ", 2)[1]);
            }
            // remove is line is empty of null
            lines.removeIf(line -> (line == null || line.trim().length()==0));
        }
        return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

Sample Run:

```
[2.0, Test_2e.mdf, 25, 10, 50, 20, 10, 15, Log to Both, logfile_1.lgf]
```

Another way of doing it ....

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(configureClass("c:/file.txt")));
    }

    public static String[] configureClass(String fileName) throws IOException {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        // try with resources
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            stream
                .filter(line -> line.contains(": "))
                .forEach(line -> results.add(line.substring(line.indexOf(": ")+2, line.length())));
        }
        return results.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```